# Многочисленный переход между сценами

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть несколько уровней, между которыми есть сцена, которая отвечает за переход на следующий уровень, можно ли сделать так, чтобы за это отвечал один скрипт?

Comment: за что именно "за это"?

Comment: За переход между сценами

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно, другие же делают.
Пишете скрипт который получает в паблик методе на вход имя сцены которую нужно загрузить. Далее в вашей сцене создается несколько кнопок, на каждую кнопку прописываете на OnClick вызов вышеописанного метода и указываете ему в параметр для передачи в метод название требуемой сцены.

Проще некуда

Comment: Вы описали так называемое «меню» игры, но у меня другая ситуация, допустим мы прошли уровень у нас загружается новая сцена, на которой есть кнопка «следующий уровень» , таких уровней много и на каждую кнопку вешать скрипт с переходом на следующий уровень как-то много скриптов получается, следовательно вопрос, можно ли как то оптимизировать это все в один скрипт

Comment: кнопки динамически создаются? Наименования сайтов у вас по какой то схеме наверняка идут. Кто мешает написать скрипт для кнопки который будет при генерации кнопки в некую паблик переменную записывать имя сцены для перехода. А дальше пусть при клике по мыши скрипт запускается и делает переход (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html). Ручками настраивать не придется, ну и огороды городить со сложными скриптами тоже.